# Open Links In Another TabPage WebControl

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, awesomium

I have a tabControl with two tabPages each with their own Awesomium WebConrol. I need links from one WebControl to open in the other WebControl. I'm currently using VS 2012.

How would that work? Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `target="_blank"` to your links. This way you will be able to capture `webControl.ShowCreatedWebView` event. In this event you will have target link `e.TargetURL`. You can load it to another webControl object, like in initialisation.

Your link:

```
<a href="http://www......" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Your code (webControl1 in first tab, this.webControl2 in second):

```
this.webControl1.ShowCreatedWebView += this.webControl1_ShowCreatedWebView;

private void webControl1_ShowCreatedWebView(object sender, Awesomium.Core.ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
{
    webControl2.Source = e.TargetURL;
}
```